# What happened to the Node type definitions?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, typescript, webstorm

I've updated to WebStorm 11 and suddenly I don't have the Node Globalslibrary definitions any more (*I think it was called Node Globals*)?

As such I get squiggly lines for core Node objects like `JSON`:

[image: JSON.stringify]

---

I've just added the `node-DefinitelyTyped` library, that's got rud of the squiggles under `JSON` but now t says that `stringify()` is not a function:

[image: stringify not recognised.]

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Node Globals` library anymore, it has been merged with Node Core library that can be configured and enabled in `Settings/Languages & frameworks/Node.js and NPM`

Comment: What was the thinking behind that?  It seems like it's not totally merged.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is not a nodejs thing, so don't include the node.d.ts, it is part of JavaScript, and TypeScript holds all the language definitions in a file called [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/cloud9ide/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts) or lib.es6.d.ts (In case you are outputting into ES6).

Your problem should not happen at all, unless you "told" WebStorm to use a specific version of TypeScript that was configured to ignore the lib.d.ts (And this can be done! by adding `--noLib` to the compiler)

Comment: Hmm...  but when I included `node-DefinitelyTyped` it recognised the `JSON` object.

Comment: Because there's a definition of JSON in the node.d.ts in the global scope. but there it was defined in the type of the existing JSON interface but in your case it does not exist

Comment: OK, so I didn't used to get squiggles in WS10, but now I do.  What's changed?

Comment: Try to create a new web project (Don't use tell it that it's TypeScript) and then just add a test.ts, try your JSON there and tell me what happened